# What is the use of key property in terrform config

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In this declaration, what is the use of `key` field? Can we give any value we like?

```
terraform {   backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "StorageAccount-ResourceGroup"
    storage_account_name = "abcd1234"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"   } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Key` parameter keeps the `Terraform state file name` as a Blob within the Blob Container within the Blob Storage Account.

No matter which name you assign to `Key`, the TF state blob will be created with that name.

For a detailed explanation, you can refer to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/azurerm.html).